# Navigation Controller -- Server Driven Data

Tags: iphone

I have to show a navigation view where number of views are server dependent. So I cannot hardcode the view controllers. Is there any way I can use 1 view controller and the data will be sent by server. So essentially it will work like this:
1. Get data from server... show on nav view using nav controller.
2. Once I tap on one entity... I get another set of data from server... using the same controller show that on the screen... ans so on... as I am not sure till what level we can drill down.
3. Once user tap on the back button... I will use the data cached locally to present in the same view...

Do see any issue here. I am wondering if I can push the same controller class' object multiple times in the stack.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as they're different objects it will work fine.

```
YourNavViewController *firstNavViewController = [[YourNavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewXib" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstNavViewController animated:YES];
[firstNavViewController release];
```

then later onto that one:

```
YourNavViewController *secondNavViewController = [[YourNavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewXib" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondNavViewController animated:YES];
[secondNavViewController release];
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

No problem at all. You can dynamically push UIViewControllers into your UINavigationControllers viewController array. You should, as you mentioned, implement a mechanism for caching content on the device, so you don't have to reload everything all the time.

One approach would be through an xml structure that you load from the server only if it differs from what you have stored locally on the device (compare e.g. through hashes, version numbers of update timestamps).

Answer (score 0):

You can't push the same *object* on the stack multiple times, but it sounds like you want to instantiate the same *class* multiple times, and push each of *those* objects.

So if the data you were collecting was XML (for example) and you had a hierarchy of objects you were parsing from an NSXMLParser class, for each level in the hierarchy, you could create a new view object containing the data at that level, and push that.